# change UIImage from MKAnnotation in the MKMapView

Tags: ios, uiimage, mkmapview, mkannotationview, mapkit

I have a mapView with only on MKAnnotation, that has a costume image. When the user changes the mapType, I need to change the image of that annotation.

The way I did that was to remove the annotation from the map, and insert another with the correct image, bu i don't think is the best way. It takes about 1 ou 2 seconds to show the new image.

How can I do it without remove the annotation and drop another?

Thanks,

RL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `viewForAnnotation:` instance method of the map view (not the same as its delegate method with a similar name) to get the current view of the annotation and force the image change explicitly.

For example, at the place where the map type is changed:

```
MKAnnotationView *av = [mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];

if (mapView.mapType == MKMapTypeHybrid)
    av.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"hybrid.png"];
else
    av.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"standard.png"];
```

However, you should add the exact same if-statement to the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method also so when the map view later calls the delegate method itself, it will set the correct image also.

You may want to move the image-setting logic to a common method that you can call from the place where you change the map type and from the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method (the `MKAnnotationView` object would be passed as a parameter).  If the logic is in one place, you don't have to remember to keep both places in sync.